# Strange error when linking libprotobuf-lite library in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, protocol-buffers

I want to use the protobuf librabry in an IOS app, so I added `libprotobuf-lite.a` to my project and also set `Header Search Paths` to the protobuf src folder, but I'm getting a strange error in the `wire_format_lite.h` file in the `FieldType` enum inside the `WireFormatLite` object. This is the enum:

```
enum FieldType {

    TYPE_DOUBLE         = 1,

    TYPE_FLOAT          = 2,

    TYPE_INT64          = 3,

    TYPE_UINT64         = 4,

...........................................

    TYPE_BOOL           = 8,

    TYPE_STRING         = 9,

..........................................

    TYPE_SINT32         = 17,

    TYPE_SINT64         = 18,

    MAX_FIELD_TYPE      = 18,

  };
```

The error is on the `TYPE_BOOL` line saying "`Expected }`". And because of this error I am getting some others errors in `wire_format_lite_inl.h` file of some missing fields from this enum (`TYPE_UINT32`, `TYPE_SINT32`, `TYPE_SINT64`). If I comment the `TYPE_BOOL` line all errors disappear, it remains only the line where `TYPE_BOOL` it is used.

Does anyone else experience this problem and have a solution for this ?

I use protobuf 2.5.0 for c++, and XCode 4.6.2 .

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for this problem. I didn't add the corect path in the Search Header Path. My path was /Users/myuser/Downloads/protobuf2.5.0/src, but this has included the object files too (.o files). I have change the path to: /Users/myuser/Downloads/protobuf2.5.0/src/google/protobuf.